# NgRx - Update property in state while looping through an array

Tags: rxjs, state, ngrx, reduce

I have the following action in a reducer:

The state currently looks like this:

```
{

"todo1": {
    { id: 1, name: 'todo1'},
    "count": "3"
},
"todo2": {
     { id: 2, name: 'todo2'},
     "count": "4"
},
"todo3": {
   { id: 3, name: 'todo3'},
     "count": "10"
}
}
```

The payload is going to be an array of todo items: ['todo1','todo2','todo3']

I want to clear the counts properties for all the todo items in the store.

```
on(ClearCountValueForAll, (state, payload) => {

  let newState = Object.assign(state)

  payload.todos.forEach(function (item) {
  
    newState = {
      ...state,
      todos: {
        ...state.todos,
        [item]: {
          ...state.todos[item],
          count: 0
        },
      },
    }
  });
  console.log(newState)
  return state;
})
```

Not sure what i am doing wrong here. Any help would be much appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your main problem is that inside the loop in each iteration you are using the original `...state` to calculate the newState. So your `newState` will always be the original state with only the count of the last item of the array reset to 0.

Answer (score 0):

How about something along these lines?

```js
const newState = { ...state };
payload.todos.forEach(item => newState.todos[item].count = 0);
return newState;
```